# fetch patch request is not allowed

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, fetch-api

I have two apps one is a react front end and the second one is the rails-api app.

I have been happily using [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) till I needed to send PATCH method to the server.

I am getting:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks. Method patch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

but the OPTIONS response from the server includes a PATCH method in a list of Access-Control-Allow-Methods:

[image]

This is how the fetch is implemented:

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'                                            
const API_PATH = 'api/v1/'

fetch(API_URL + API_PATH + 'tasks', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  method: 'patch',                                                              
  body: JSON.stringify( { task: task } )                                        
})
```

POST, GET, DELETE are set up pretty much the same and they are working fine.

Any idea what is going on here?

**UPDATE:**

Method patch is case sensitive:

https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js#L200

Not to sure if this is intended or a bug.

**UPDATE 2**

This is intended and the method type PATCH needs to be case sensitive.
Updating the line from fetch method to:

```
method: 'PATCH'
```

fixes the problem.

https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/254

Comment: it looks like there might be a bug in isomorphic-fetch as the request will work if I will change the method name to POST but it is case insensitive for post, get delete....

Comment: As a side note, the header for allowed methods in a response to an `OPTIONS` request is `Allow:`. Your response is using a different header (`Access-Control-Allow-Methods:`).

Comment: @drhining sorry I don't understand. OPTIONS is used to find out from the server which requests are allowed to do CORS. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:` returns the list of all allowed methods so the PATCH is allowed. The "issue" is with the fetch library it self and it is explained in the updates

Comment: Regardless I think you should add it as an answer, because it's the solution to your problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue with "whatwg-fetch". I was passing lowercase "patch" instead of uppercase "PATCH"

Comment: Thanks for posting this and your updated findings.

Comment: Got me on the findings – changing 'patch' to 'PATCH' solved the problem. Where are the build-in enums when you need them? :) Thanks for posting the update.

Comment: Same as @JamesPerih... Replacing `'patch'` with `'PATCH'` solved the "issue" :/

Comment: Found this after an hour of debugging - thanks for posting the update!

Comment: Thanks for the updates! For me, case sensetive was the key. Frustrating.

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar problem with reactJS front end and rails API using Rack::Cors, and adding `patch` to the list of allowed methods solved the problem for me.

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :options]
  end
end
```

Comment: This solution helped me fix my Javascript `fetch` problem to my page in PHP. I added my solution.

Comment: This disables CORS token check for GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS requests. making your application vulnerable to attacks... instead you should pass the cors_token along with your request in the request header.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error while `PATCH` was all caps. I was also getting this error with `DELETE` and `PUT` too. I checked the headers of my `fetch` and I saw a `OPTIONS` method. I was using the `isomorphic-fetch` lib here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch

The fix for me was to add to my PHP page:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH');
```

Without this, in Firefox 53 I would keep getting the javascript error:

> NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

The fetch I was doing was this:

```
try {
    await fetch('https://my.site.com/', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: 'id=12&day=1'
    });
} catch(ex) {
    console.error('ex:', ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code
**_method: 'PATCH'**

```
return (
        fetch(API_ROOT + route, {
            _method: 'PATCH',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': ''
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            return res
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    );
```

**Another Way is**
*insert method in headers*

```
headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            '_method': 'PATCH',
            'Authorization': ''
        }
```

**it helps you**

```
return (
        fetch(API_ROOT + route, {
            method: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                '_method': 'PATCH',
                'Authorization': ''
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return res
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    );
```

Comment: This also works for NGINX (Reverse Proxy). It solved my "API 400 Bad Request during PATCH Request". Perfect!

Comment: `fetch(API_ROOT + route, {_method: 'PATCH'}` has error it should be `fetch(API_ROOT + route, {method: 'PATCH'}`