# The mystery of PATCH request and CORS headers

Tags: javascript, express, cors, patch

I ran into the issue already described in these questions (with no clear answer as far as I can see):

- [Fetch PATCH request not allowed (CORS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395127/fetch-patch-request-not-allowed-cors)
- https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/252
- Probably a bunch more...

And I thought I ask it again, with clearly reproducible steps.

### Backend

I have a simple, self contained [express](https://expressjs.com) server set up like so:

```js
const express = require('express')

const methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']

const app = express()

methods.forEach((method) => {
  const path = `/${method}-method-test`

  // Preflight request, with same path but OPTIONS method
  app.options(path, (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin') ?? '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', `${method}, ${method.toUpperCase()}`)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-custom-request-header')
    res.end()
  })

  // Actual endpoint
  app[method](path, (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin') ?? '*')
    res.send(method)
  })
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Methods test listening on http://localhost:5000'))
```

Here we have an endpoint handling preflight requests, that:

- Has the "proper" `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that allows any origin
- Has the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` that allows the given method, with both upper and lowercase (someone mentioned casing might be an issue)
- Has the proper `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers, so our custom request headers are allowed, in case the clients wants to send them.

And the actual endpoint:

- Has the "proper" `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that allows any origin
- Has the proper `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` headers, so our custom response headers are allowed in case the clients wants to receive them.

It's respecting all instructions (as far as I can tell): described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

### Browser

I have a simple test case for these, that runs in the browser:

```js
describe('Http methods', () => {
  const methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']

  methods.forEach((method) =>
    describe(method, () => {
      // Check as a simple request if possible (pre-flight request ommited, goes straight to the endpoint)
      it(`should allow a simple ${method} request in the browser`, async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/${method}-method-test`, { method })
        const body = await response.text()
        chai.expect(body).to.be.eq(method)
      })

      // Force pre-flight request with custom request header
      it(`should allow ${method} request with forced pre-flight request`, async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/${method}-method-test`, {
          method,
          headers: { 'x-custom-request-header': 'hi' },
        })
        const body = await response.text()
        chai.expect(body).to.be.eq(method)
      })
    }),
  )
})
```

This first checks the request first without any bells and whistles, then tries to send `x-custom-request-header` so we can test the preflight request too.

### The result

All tests work as expected, except `PATCH`. Furthermore, the browser doesn't even seem to attempt a pre-flight request for `PATCH`. This seems to be consistent across Chrome and Firefox (the 2 browser I have installed):

[image: Patch request wtf]

When I test this same request in an API explorer tool (Insomnia), the endpoint is responding, and the headers are there (both for the pre-flight and the actual request):

[image: Insomnia]

### The question summarized

- What is different about `PATCH`, when it comes to CORS?
- Is it documented? (if it is, where?)
- Could express be doing something unexpected?
- How do I fix this?

Comment: Could not recreate - there's not enough information to run the test suite, and when I make a request from the browser to `PATCH http://localhost:5000/patch-method-test` it succeeds, with or without the custom header.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you paste it here as a comment how you are making the patch request?

Comment: Same as you, with fetch: `fetch("http://localhost:5000/patch-method-test", { method: "PATCH" })`

Comment: What’s different is that to browsers, `patch` and `PATCH` are not the same method name; instead, they are treated case-sensitively — while in contrast, browsers treat `DELETE`, `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, `POST`, and `PUT` case-insensitively. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#methods. So `const methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']` should instead be `const methods = ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']`. HTTP method names are defined to be case-sensitive, by the HTTP specs. But browsers are forgiving and treat most common ones case-insensitively — except for PATCH.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you, uppercasing was the issue. This is absurd, I'm going to write a quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR

`PATCH` is case sensitive so `patch` **from the browser's side** is not the same as `PATCH`. Docs: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#methods (thanks @sideshowbarker)

On the server side also make sure to allow `PATCH` when sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header.