# Patch with CORS on nginx and vue-router

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

I am hosting a nodejs server, as well as a separate website through nginx. The website communicates to the server via the html5 `fetch`.

On the server, I have a route for `/api.profile` which will allow the user to PATCH information. Using Postman to test, everything works correctly, however when trying to send a PATCH request from the website I get the following error:

> fetch API cannot load http://192.168.0.205:3000/api.profile. Method patch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

This leads me to believe that it's the fetch API or an nginx issue. I've tried multiple articles and configurations online, however I can't fix the issue.
The following is a dump of my nginx config to try allow CORS as well as html5 history mode for vue-router.

```
user  developer staff;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
error_log  /Library/Logs/nginx/error.log;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    # st login: Mon Jun 19 11:43:00 on ttys003
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;

      root /Users/Developer/Desktop/Work/mentorconnect_client/web;

      index index.html;

      server_name localhost;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,Origin,Accept';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'PATCH') {
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
      }

      location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
      }

      location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
      }    
    }

}
```

On the server, in `app.js`, I have the following to enable CORS:

```
let corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, next) => {
        next(null, true)
    },
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS']
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

And the profile route is setup using cors (global.cors is the instance of cors with the config):

```
app.options('/api.profile', global.cors)
app.patch('/api.profile', global.cors, (req, res) => {
```

Here are the response headers from the request vua the browser
[image]

Comment: If you’re using lowercase `patch` in the fetch call in your frontend code, try changing it to uppercase `PATCH`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666680/fetch-patch-request-is-not-allowed