# React-Redux: PATCH with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a patch to modify some informations using a form.

I take the new data, if they are modify and then create a new FormData. Then I pass the id and the formdata to do a patch. But something in the patch goes wrong.

I have a page in which I take the previous information( I pass these informations using `react-router-dom` and have a form to modify the data.

**FormPage.js**

When the submit button is press I call this:

```
  class MeetingModify extends Components{
//the state taken from the previous page

     handleSubmit(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                const idmeet = this.state.meet.id

            var newMeet = new FormData();

            if(this.state.information != this.props.location.state.information){
                newMeet.append("information", this.state.information);
            }
            if(this.state.date != this.props.location.state.date){
                newMeet.append("date", this.state.date);
            }
            if(this.state.hours != this.props.location.state.hours){
                newMeet.append("hours", this.state.hours);
            }

            this.props.changeMeeting(idmeet, newMeet);    
        }

render(){
return(
//..form..
)

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeMeeting: (idmeet, newMeet) => dispatch(changeMeeting(idmeeting, newMeet)),
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MeetingModify);
```

in the **Actions.js**

```
export const changeMeeting = (idmeet, newMeet) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(meeturl + '/' + idmeet , {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: newMeet,
    })
    .then(
      (response) => {return response.json()},
      (error) => console.log("An error occurred.", error)
    )
    .then((newMeet) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "MEETING_PATCH",
        newMeet: newMeet
      });
    });
  }
```

How can I do to execute the patch ?? Thank you

If you need more details I can edit :)

EDIT. I don't understand why it gives me a CORS error ( I have resolved it, infact for the other method like post or get it works. )

I have tried to console log the `body: newMeet` and if I use form data is like: 
`["information", "new information"]`

I tried to the same with Postman (or cocoaRestClient) and the curl is:

`--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'information=new information'`

I see on postman the javascript - fetch:

```
var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();

urlencoded.append("information", "New Information");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```

It's the same to mine...

Comment: can you please check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666680/fetch-patch-request-is-not-allowed

Comment: @LakshmanKambam I saw this answer.... I have tried also the _method (I have edited before my post with this but when I inspect I found that is in this way the method become a GET)

Comment: Method patch is case sensitive.. correct that and let me know!

Comment: Infact I have wrote `PATCH` :(

Comment: not sure if it's intended or a fix. but if you can provide more info I can help you.

Comment: No as you Can see i wrote it in the right way

Comment: I can't understand why It doesn't work. I have tried this with postman, I have set the same things but nothing..